# Database design for products with multiple prices

Tags: sql, database

What would be the best database design for this:

I have a list of products and a list of clients.
Each product has assigned 9 different prices
Each client has assigned one of those prices for every product.

IT would be something like this:

```
PRODUCTS
id
name
price1
price2
price3
price4
price5
price6
price7
price8
price9
```

CLIENTS
id
name
price_Code

Any idea?

Comment: denormalized table with client id, price and product id?

Comment: Is it always exactly 9 different prices? What if there are less or more?

Comment: Yeah, it is always 9 prices for each product to choose from.

Comment: @TYH from what he has written the constraint is the number of clients: `Each client has assigned one of those prices for every product` so it seems there are 9 clients in total right now?

Comment: There are hundreds of products, and hundreds of clients.

Comment: @DrCopyPaste what I meant to say, was what if in the future that number changes. The design of the Tables should easily accommodate this. Otherwise he is stuck adding columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some information is missing.

First, you need a product table

```
Product
-------
Product ID
Product Description
...
```

Next, you need a product price table

```
ProductPrice
------------
ProductPrice ID
Product ID
Price
```

Next, you have a client table

```
Client
------
Client ID
Client Name
...
```

Finally, you have a client product price table.  The missing information is, does the price for the client change if the price changes in the product price table?

```
ClientProductPrice
------------------
Client ID
Product ID
???
```

If the price for the client changes, then the ??? is the Product Price ID.  You don't need the Product ID because you can get that from the product price table.

If the price for the client does not change, then the ??? is the Price.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. As you said, the price for the client would change if the price changes for the product, but then, why use a ClientProductPrice table? wouldn't it be better to just add the field "Product Price ID" to the Clients table?

Comment: @EVL: The client table has one row per client.  A client can have multiple products.

Comment: Because the product price is NOT an attribute of the entity "Client" and this would be in violation of the 2nd normal form.

Answer (score 2):

This makes no sense. Prices are examples of diachronic properties: meaning they represent a value *at a given time*.

What you want is a price table with 2 dates in it.

```
Prices
  productID:long
  effectiveDate:Date
  endDate:Date
```

Then when you want the current price, you have two choices. The most common one is to join the row that has a null for the endDate field.

The other reason you want to do this is that you might be asked to change the price of a product on a given date.

Answer (score 1):

You need `PRODUCT_PRICE` table which stores any number of price.

And `PRODUCT_PRICE_CLIENT` table stores which client buy on which product price.

Remove `price1 price2 price3 price4 price5 price6 price7 price8 price9` from PRODUCT table.